# How do I set up my multiline wordWrap TextField to automatically resize its width when height is set?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to create a textfield extension that:
When width is set, automatically resize height by the content of text. Easy done by autosize left, word wrap true, multiline true.
When height is set, automatically resize width by the content of text. **Here is my problem.**

When both width and height set aren't a case I am interested in.

I've tried several things off the internet, I am stumped.

Comment: This just off the top of my head (untested) but try setting the one you want to resize to `NaN` (not a number). A lot of auto-GUI elements are only enabled when the manual counterpart is disabled and `NaN` is the `null` version of a Number. Again, this is untested but it is a single line of code for you to test. If that works, I would suggest extending `TextField` and overriding the height/width setters to automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution is impossible, as if the text field contains too many newlines to display within a given height, no matter what width you assign, the text field will be unable to display all the lines. Partial solution is presented by greetification, but it lacks some features one should be aware of. First, no matter what you do, you should not set height to value less than font height, or the text field will not be able to display a single line. Second, if `wordWrap` is set to false, and `multiline` to true, the resultant `textWidth` is the largest desirable width for your text field, so if you adjust the width like greetification advises, stop once you reach the recorded `textWidth`, as further increases are pointless.

```
function setHeight(newHeight:Number):void {
  var tw:Number;
  var th:Number;
  if (myTextField.wordwrap) {
    myTextField.wordwrap=false;
    tw=myTextField.textWidth;
    th=myTextField.textHeight;
    myTextField.wordwrap=true;
  } else {
    tw=myTextField.textWidth;
    th=myTextField.textHeight;
  }
  if (newHeight<th) newHeight=th+2; // as below
  myTextField.height = newHeight;

  while((myTextField.textHeight > myTextField.height)&&(myTextField.width<tw)) {
    myTextField.width += 100;
  }
  if (myTextField.width>tw) myTextField.width=tw+2; // "2" depends on text format
  // and other properties, so either play with it or assume a number big enough
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but it should work:

```
function setHeight(newHeight:Number):void {
  myTextField.height = newHeight;

  while(myTextField.textHeight > myTextField.height) {
    myTextField.width += 100;
  }
}
```